# Installed Scrapyd on rackspace and want to access on local machine

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I have installed Scrapyd Service on Rack Space. I have dedicated IP. I can access scrapyd on server only [http://localhost:6800]. I want to access this from my local computer and want to deploy spiders later on. I need help to access it like http://someip:6800

Looking forward to hear from you.

Answer (score 0):

Open the port 6800 of your server then you can access it from any machine. You can see how to open port in linux in this link:

http://www.tixati.com/optimize/open-ports-linux.html